# Folding Mercurial changesets without altering history

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tree, rebase

Is there a way to collapse a few sequential Mercurial changesets into a tree view with a single description while maintaining full history? Kind of like rebasing, but displayed so that no history is altered.

These "fixed", "really fixed" and "really really fixed" changesets are driving me nuts.

**Update:** I found the [Collapse Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) and the [Histedit Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension), but both rewrite history like `rebase`. I wish there was a way of adding 'collapse' information with a commit message as a purely visual layer, without throwing away any changeset information.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this in mercurial. But what about having the extra changesets is bothering you? Your past code is always buggy, slow, and low-featured: that's why you kept developing it. There's no harm in having changesets that weren't quite right.

You can't control your repo's entire history; you can only change its current state. And if its current state has the bug fixed, there's no problem. Let the past be.

Comment: Ignoring clunky changesets breaks down in a team where code reviewing "really really fixed" changesets costs valuable development time.

Comment: Why are they looking at intermediate commits? They should be looking at the overall effects of the changes; that is, the diff from before the first commit in the code review to the last commit in the review.

Answer (score 0):

> collapse a few sequential Mercurial changesets into a tree view with a single description while maintaining full history?

How you see it? One changeset with history of more-than-one?!

**Short answer**: No, you can't - or you have single collapsed changeset or you have rangeset

**Longer answer**: Not in single place, but at least in two it can be reached, if your repository wasn't published yet (because you can't edit history of already pushed repository - shared repository isn't under your exclusive control).

If repository with rangeset in question met the above requirements, you can try

- Have one repo with unmodified history for development (hereinafter DEV)
- Have one repo (clone of DEV) with collapsed history to sharing to public (hereinafter PUBLIC)

Suggested workflow:

- Clone DEV (existing now) to PUBLIC
- Collapse rangeset in PUBLIC by any preferred way (thus - rewrite it's history)
- Publish PUBLIC
- Continue your work on DEV
- When needed, transfer changes to PUBLIC (you'll get anonymous branch with history, diverged at collapsed rangeset)
- Linearize history on PUBLIC with rebase
- Publish PUBLIC

Repeat 4 latest points in cycle during development